# How does Spark DataFrame find out some lines that only appear once?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to eliminate some rows that only appear once in the ‘county’ column, which is not conducive to my statistics.

I used groupBy+count to find：

```
fault_data.groupBy("county").count().show()
```

The data looks like this：

```
+----------+-----+
|    county|count|
+----------+-----+
|       A|    117|
|       B|     31|
|       C|      1|
|       D|    272|
|       E|      1|
|       F|      1|
|       G|    280|
|       H|      1|
|       I|      1|
|       J|      1|
|       K|    112|
|       L|     63|
|       M|     18|
|       N|     71|
|       O|      1|
|       P|      1|
|       Q|     82|
|       R|      2|
|       S|     31|
|       T|      2|
+----------+-----+
```

Next, I want to eliminate the data whose count is 1.
But when I wrote it like this, it was wrong：

```
fault_data.filter("count(county)=1").show()
```

The result is：

```
Aggregate/Window/Generate expressions are not valid in where clause of the query.
Expression in where clause: [(count(county) = CAST(1 AS BIGINT))]
Invalid expressions: [count(county)];
Filter (count(county#7) = cast(1 as bigint))
+- Relation [fault_id#0,fault_type#1,acs_way#2,fault_1#3,fault_2#4,province#5,city#6,county#7,town#8,detail#9,num#10,insert_time#11] JDBCRelation(fault_data) [numPartitions=1]
```

So I want to know the right way, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
fault_data.groupBy("county").count().where(col("count")===1).show()
```

Comment: If OP wants to "eliminate the data whose count is 1", you should probably look where `count` is *not* 1